# How to set carret for combination characters(set composition)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, range

I would like to make sure that the letters I am composing are not in the combination.
We tried to check through the Range in javascript, but related information could not be verified. Please let me know how to do this.

Also, when I set the Caret, I want to set it in the form of composing characters, but it does not work well. So I dragged the current character to express it. Is there a way to set the Caret as shown below?

Get the caret position with below the code

```
let range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
range.startContainer();
range.endContainer();
range.startOffset();
range.endOffset();
```

Set drag the letter with below the code

```
const [startCaret, endCaret] = getCaretPosition();
setCaretPosition(startCaret, endCaret+1);
```

setCaretPosition function is made of below the code

```
let range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(startElement, startOffset);
range.setEnd(endElement, endOffset);
```

image link : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ryulth/Co-Editor/refactor/refactoring/frontend/hangul.PNG

Comment: I find that IME(https://www.w3.org/TR/ime-api/#IME).
I think that maybe I can set caret with composition. but I don't find how to set composition or how to get composition flag.
Just I can get composition flag from isComposing var of event.
but I need to get isComposing flag whenever.